# alias used not modifying the actual contents of STL container

Tags: c++, stl, reference

I am unable to understand the following behaviour. When I use `currPMap` to modify the value, the value at the actual location is not modified. Why is that so.

I checked with the reference the `operator[]` and `at()` return reference and so this should have worked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef map<int, int> intMap;
typedef map<int, int>::iterator mapIt;

int main(void) {
    vector< map<int, intMap > > b(2);
    int curr=0, next=1;
    map<int, intMap> currPMap = b.at(curr);
    (currPMap[4])[2] = 3;    //modified by currPMap.
    cout<<((b.at(curr))[4])[2]<<endl;
    ((b.at(curr))[4])[2] = 3;    //modified using the actual vector.
    cout<<((b.at(curr))[4])[2]<<endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0
3
```

P.S.: I know what I am doing here can be achieved by many other ways in this setting, but this is not the actual program. This is just the explicit version of the problem that I am facing with my code. I would be grateful if someone answers what is wrong in this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map<int, intMap> currPMap = b.at(curr);
```

That's not an alias (aka reference); that's a copy. If you want a reference, you need to declare it thusly:

```
map<int, intMap> & currPMap = b.at(curr);
                 ^
```

Beware that the reference may be invalidated if you add or remove elements to the vector, since vectors need to move their elements to maintain a contiguous array.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are getting a *copy* of a map here, not an *alias*:

```
map<int, intMap> currPMap = b.at(curr); // currMap is a copy of b[0]
```

You then modify the copy, not the map stored in the vector.

What you need is a reference:

```
map<int, intMap>& currPMap = b.at(curr); // currMap refers to b[0]
```

Comment: This site says that at return a reference. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam exactly, which is why you can assign the return value to a reference. But you are making a copy.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. Then why does the compiler did not show any error/warning messages for what I have did. Is it correct. If yes then how.(Sorry for a question in comments)

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam because you are allowed to make copies of objects from references to other objects. Both versions are correct, they just do different things.

Comment: So this is kind of analogus for the `*`(dereference operator) which we have in case of pointers. Am I correct.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam not quite. It is more to do with what you do with the result of the expression on the RHS. In one case, you initialize a value, so you get a copy. In the other, you initialize a *reference*, so the reference is just an alias to the result of the RHS.